# Python text-based random questions quiz

Tags: python-3.4

This is a text-based quiz example, where the program is supposed to give 5 questions for the user to answer in a random order. The problem is that it works perfectly, but only gives 3 random questions, then stops.

```
import random

question1=["The answer is A","A","a"]
question2=["The answer is B","B","b"]
question3=["The answer is A","A","a"]
question4=["The answer is F","F","f"]
question5=["The answer is A","A","a"]

questions=[question1,question2,question3,question4,question5]

used_questions=[]

while len(used_questions)!=len(questions):

    random_question=random.choice(questions)

    while random_question in used_questions:
        random_question=random.choice(questions)

    used_questions.append(random_question)

    print([random_question[0]])

    players_answer=input("")

    if players_answer in random_question:
        print("\nCorrect!")
    else:
       print("\nWrong!")
```

Comment: Your approach is rather convoluted, just do `random.shuffle(questions)` and iterate over the resulting list of questions (now in a random order)

Comment: Because some of your questions are **identical**, after three questions, there are no questions left that have not already been asked. So your `while random_question in used_questions` loop becomes an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions 1, 3, and 5 are identical, so you only have three unique questions, so only three questions are displayed. `random_question in used_questions` evaluates to True as long as one element of `used_questions` is equal to  `random_question`; they do not have to refer to the exact same list in memory.

As mentioned in the comments and other answers, shuffling the list is an easier approach here.

```
import random

questions=[
    ["The answer is A","A","a"],
    ["The answer is B","B","b"],
    ["The answer is A","A","a"],
    ["The answer is F","F","f"],
    ["The answer is A","A","a"]
]

random.shuffle(questions)
for question in questions:
    print(question[0])
    players_answer=input("")
    if players_answer in question:
        print("\nCorrect!")
    else:
       print("\nWrong!")
```

Result:

```
The answer is F
F

Correct!
The answer is A
B

Wrong!
The answer is A
Q

Wrong!
The answer is B
B

Correct!
The answer is A
A

Correct!
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I would have probably never realised

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler approach is to use `shuffle`:

```
random.shuffle(questions)
```

This shuffles your questions in place. You can then just loop round the `questions`.